# How to Style an hr Tag Using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

How can I style an hr tag?

```
#footer hr
{
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
}
```

This doesn't work in firefox. I even tried `background:`, but that didn't work. Is there some other way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Its working 
you need to just use hr in div with your css id footer. As like below

```
<div id="footer">
   <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try background: instead of background-image:

See here for a working example in Firefox:

http://playground.genelocklin.com/gradient-hr/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the height of the `<hr />`

look [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YGjbT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try making a div like so:

```
CSS:
div.hr{
    background-image:url('yourimage.jpg');
    height: 5px;
    width:  400px; /*About the size of the content area that you are putting it in*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

HTML:
<div id="hr">
</div>
```

Have any questions?

EDIT: 
With taking a look at Charlie's answers, you could try something like this:

```
<div id="footer">
    <hr id="footer" />
</div>

#footer
{
    height:10px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.myhr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #333, #ccc); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    hrshadow {
        height: 12px;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

/****************************/


Newhr {
    height: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
Newhr:before { 
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -31px;    
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .hrstyle {
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        border-top: medium double #333;
        color: #333;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .hrstyle:after {
        content: "§";
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative; 
        top: -0.7em;  
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 0 0.25em;
        background: white;
    }


/****dashed line *****/

.dash_hr {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
    background: #999;
}
```